# Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library

Tags: android

I am writing a game, and I have huge native library, I am trying to load my native library in my main activity like

```
 static {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("mylib");
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Unsatisfied Link error: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

I have tested this code on many devices in house, I don't get this error. but from my published I do get logs with "**Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library**". NOTE: This crash is not universal, only few people are getting this crash

- Is it problem where the library is put in exported apk ? I have now library put into /libs/armabi/libmylib.so automatically by eclipse?
- Is it some thing to do with version of android ? I am supporting android versions since 2.3 (API level 9)
- or do I need to load library from different place?
- or am I missing something very important
- Is it problem with whole app being installed on SDCARD ?

More Info on crash is : load_segments: 68 failed to map segment from mylib.so

Comment: I have huge native library, how huge? Maybe it does not meet some memory requirments and the system can not load.

Comment: ~ 7MB (debug version)

Comment: It is definitly not a memory issue. In what device do you expiremented this issue?

Comment: What processor architecture are you compiling it against?  Most newer devices use ARM7 processor, while some of the older ones use ARM6.  If you compile the native library against ARM7, it may not load on ARM6.

Comment: @blackbelt: The problematic devices is Desire HD, This is from google play reviews. I can not reproduce this issue with my HTC desire though.

Comment: I don't understand why the downvote.  This is a good, well written question.

Answer (score 14):

Considering that your app works correctly on most of the devices and only sometimes gives you the error, it's safe to assume that the library is packaged correctly in the APK and that its size/memory footprint is also acceptable.

As such, I'll go on the whim and suggest that the problem is with the build/compile architecture of the library.  Most newer Android devices use ARM7 processor.  It's quite likely that your library is compiled against ARM7 architecture as well.  Some older devices, especially those running Android 2.3, use ARM6 processor (I have one such device that I use for testing - LG GT540 running Android 2.3.3), which is not forward-compatible with ARM7 architecture. I have seen a crash with error similar to the one you indicated (*load_segments: 68 failed to map segment from mylib.so*) when I attempted to run an app designed for ARM7 on my old ARM6 phone.

There are three ways of going around this issue:

1. Compile the library against both architectures and include two separate .so files into the apk.  Then at runtime determine the type of processor and load the correct one.  Frankly, I don't know if this is even possible.
2. Create two separate apk files - one for ARM6 and one for ARM7 - then use filters in the manifest to specify the corresponding architecture.  You can upload both of them to google play for the same app - and filters in the manifest will control which one is downloaded to which device.
3. Only support ARM7 architecture by specifying device requirements in your manifest.  You will loose some customer audience, but will have less work for yourself maintaining the two versions of the app.

**EDIT:** According to NDK documentation, it can produce multiple libraries for different architectures in one go.  You can control specifically which CPUs you want to target by adding the following line into the `Application.mk` file:

```
APP_ABI := arch1 arch2 arch3 ...
```

for example,

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a mips
```

Then the build process will create different versions of the native library.  These versions will need to be placed in the final apk in directory

```
lib/<abi>/lib<name>.so
```

where  is the name of the architecture. You will then load the library with

```
System.loadLibrary("<name>");
```

Alternatively you can build separate apk files for each architecture then use multi-apk functionality on google play.

You can find all the information on architecture targeting in file `CPU-ARCH-ABIS.html` file in the `docs` subdirectory of the NDK.

Comment: Broadly I accept your answer, I think what you are suggesting is logical. however I am not sure if there is option in manifest or anywhere I could specifically build for amrv6 and armv7, I couldn't find way to fix this through android manifest

Comment: @techjeevi The architecture is not specified in the apk manifest, but in the build files for the native library.  It's later incorporated into the build app and used by google play. I'll do some digging to find an example.

Comment: @techjeevi I updated my answer with details of how to target different architectures with different versions of the native library as well as where to find more information.

Comment: I am tempted to mark this answer right, but however I am not sure if this answer really help me, see following comment

Comment: Desire HD has ARMV7 architecture, documentation clearly suggests that by default at least ARMV5TE is supported, so if my current library works on 100s of latest processors, how do you think by creating two set of library help solve this issue?

Comment: @techjeevi I am not saying that it is the solution or that it will work, just describe one possible scenario.  What you also may want to look at is the specific features of the processor that you may be using.  Two different ARM7 chips may support different set of of features - and if your native library attempts to use an unsupported feature, it may fail.  CPU-FEATURES.HTML file in the same NDK docs directory describes how to test availability of specific features at runtime. According to the NDK docs, `hello-neon` NDK sample illustrates runtime checking for specific features. Just an idea.

Comment: @techjeevi Do explore [NDK documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) for more possibilities.

Comment: @AleksG `Then at runtime determine the type of processor and load the correct one. Frankly, I don't know if this is even possible.` i believe android already does this on its own. Although there is a bug about this here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-ndk/N8FLjvM81pg/discussion

Comment: definitely helped me. it's the "lib" prefix that is omitted when loading it from java that got me. makes no sense at all. thanks!